# Creating a container for max-width of web page

Tags: html, css, responsive, styled-components

I have 3 key elements that I want to style, `header`, `container` and `footer` - I want to ensure all of these elements have a max-width of `1248px` - but when the screen size exceeds this, the content is centered and has equal margin/padding (fairly standard practise) - I'm just not entirely sure what the correct approach is, any advice would be appreciated!

codepen: https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/MWpJbWK

Header:

```
const StyledApplicationBanner = styled.header`
  background: black;
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(151, 153, 155);
`;
```

Container:

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1248px;
`;
```

Footer:

```
const StyledApplicationFooter = styled.div`
  background: ${themeProp("BLACK")};
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
`;
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 112px;
  width: 1248px;
  background: teal;
}

.container {
  flex 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1248px;
}

.footer {
  width: 1248px;
  height: 140px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="container">Container</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would usually approach this by mocking  it up in plain HTML/CSS, then convert to your component library. This type of layout is ubiquitous on the web (see also: this very page), so it's just a matter of finding one that suits and following it.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you're asking here. Does your code work or doesn't it? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: the current status is that content spans the full width of the webpage (regardless of size) - but my desire is that it only operates within the width of 1248px, with any additional space split on either side equally.

Comment: Ok, but your code seems to impose a width on the container. It's hard to help not being able to see what the rendered HTML looks like. Maybe post that as well, along with your actual usage of those variables.

Comment: Could also be done without flex if you wanted by just putting `margin: 0 auto;` on `.main` 
https://codepen.io/danjford/pen/bGqgBqb